# How to improve simple univariant time series forecasting?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a simple univariant time-series forcasting problem where my input is `10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90`. I want the model to predict the next 3 values. i.e. the output should be `100, 110, 120`.

I used stacked LSTM to do this. My code is as follows.

```
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

def split_sequence(sequence, n_steps_in, n_steps_out):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps_in
        out_end_ix = end_ix + n_steps_out
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if out_end_ix > len(sequence):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix:out_end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)

raw_seq = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps_in, n_steps_out = 5, 3
# split into samples
X, y = split_sequence(raw_seq, n_steps_in, n_steps_out)
# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, timesteps, features]
n_features = 1
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], n_features))
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_steps_out))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, verbose=0)
# demonstrate prediction
x_input = array([50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps_in, n_features))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
```

Since I am using a very straightforward example, I expected the model to predict accurately. However, the output I got was terrible (`[[135.52011 151.59491 175.79674]]`).

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this in LSTM?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a problem, a better result could be obtained by taking into consideration more previous timesteps.

Also, please take into account that Jason's Brownlee example is more relevant for us to understand how to create a dataset for time series forecasting. For decent predictions, one would need much more data.

After all, in univariate(only one feature to be considered for future predictions) problems, simpler (even statistical models) such as ARIMA,SARIMA may be better suited.

Comment: What do you mean by more data? Is it to expand the window size? Thank you :)

Comment: More data means to be much bigger dataset in essence(say array of 1.000.000 elements not raw_seq of 10 elements for instance). The window_size is the n_steps_in, and yes, the accuracy may be increased by varying this 'n_steps_in' parameter(increasing it in your case).